# Error creating SSL context

Tags: jetbrains-toolbox

I have just downloaded Jetbrains Toolbox for linux and intalled it in Deepin Linux 15.4, but after I opened the Toolbox and tried to sign in, sth wrong happened, the following is the error message:

> Error creating SSL context (error:140A90C4:SSL routines:func(169):reason(196))

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This problem is usually related to having in the system a more modern version of the SSL library than the one the software uses.

I found a solution.

```
nano ~/.toolboxrc
```

Add this line.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/openssl-1.0:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Then save it and relaunch toolbox.

Comment: I can't get it to work with the created file. I have created a new file as you suggested. But I can't see any difference do I have to do something more?

Comment: I fixed this by using this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/ALL-1486#comment=27-2035576. Using the highlighted comment.